# Auto refresh tree view odoo 15

Tags: odoo-15

I am using odoo 15 version. Assuming there is user A and User B.

User A is already landed on customer invoice tree view And after few seconds User B create a new invoice from its login id.

User A should see this new invoice on tree view without refreshing tree view.

is there any way the tree view automatically gets refreshed when a new records created?

Answer (score 0):

Automatically refreshing the tree view for one user when another user changes a record is not possible in any simple way as far as I'm aware. This would most likely require major JavaScript and Python changes to the Odoo 15 codebase.

I recently worked on a development where a client wanted similar functionality but we decided that the result was not worth the time required for such a change.